# Find n-roots of unity and put them in vector

Tags: equation-solving, complex, vector

Assume you want to find all roots of n-unity and then you want to put them in a vector. I tried to find all the roots of unity this way:

```
Solve(z^n==1,z)
```

But now i want to put them as a vector. Is there a way Matematica recognize the roots as a vector?

Comment: `r[n_] := (z /. Solve[z^n == 1, z]) // ComplexExpand`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function returns a list of all the $n$th roots of unity in order.

```
nth[n_] := Table[Exp[k 2 Pi I/n], {k, 0, n-1}];
```

You can do it with the more general code

```
nth[n_] := Table[Root[#1^n - 1 &, k], {k, n}];
```

where you can specify any polynomial of degree n.

If you want the numerical values of the roots, use `N[nth[n]]`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
{1, I}.# & /@ CirclePoints[5]
```